# How can give my app to client for testing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

hi i am developing an iphone app for a client who lives outside my country.
The client wants to check out the app every time i complete a functionality in order to note my progress and to suggest necessary changes.
How can give my app to client for testing before the project is completely done .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give them ADHOC or testing versions of your app.

It can be relatively easy to do on your own (and the instructions are easily found on Apple's ["iOS Provisioning Portal"](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action), or there are also some services available from third parties online that make the process even more straighforward.  I've heard good things about [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com), for example.

Comment: i tried testflight but i am having trouble

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to [create an ad-hoc certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html). Then use [xcode to create your archive](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/).
ps: You need the `UDID`s of your client iPhones to add the devices to the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way-

1) Add the UDIDs of your client and use the particular profile and certificates to build your app.

2) Create a signed .ipa and .plist files.(Distribute for enterprise option).

3) Simpler way to distribute it as you can put it on the dropbox and attach it in an html file.

4) Send your client the public link of that html page you've put on dropbox.

Hope it helps. :)